# Ловит значение start в телеграм боте

Tags: php, telegram-bot

Ребят помогите словить значение ссылки 
http://t.me/mybot?start=123

пробую так но не получается

```
case preg_match("~^\/start ([\d]+)$~", $text, $matches):
    // здесь нужное вам значение
    $id_ref = $matches[1];
    // далее вы что-то делаете с $id_ref
    $dataSend = array(
        'text' => $id_ref,
        'chat_id' => $chat_id,
        'reply_markup' => $justKeyboard,
    );
    $this->requestToTelegram($dataSend, "sendMessage");
    break;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

можно использовать Positive Lookbehind, чтобы найти цифры после `start=` и до конца строки

```
if (preg_match("~(?<=start=)\d+$~", 'http://t.me/mybot?start=123', $matches)) {
    $id_ref = $matches[0]; // 123
}
```

Comment: спасибо большое

Comment: извините а если так case (preg_match("~^\/start ([\d]+)$~", $message, $matches) ? true : false):

Comment: ну про case отдельный вопрос, но вы опять неправильной регуляркой пользуетесь но

Comment: у вас `switch(true) {` ?  это не очень здорово

Comment: можно поподробней у вас switch(true) { ? это не очень здорово

Comment: `case preg_mattch... :` как вся конструкция выглядит?